# How to use POCO on multiple ORM(EF,NHibernate) without tight coupling?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created 2 (POCO) classes for my domain,Question and Answer(One Question can have many Answers).
I created EF model with Code Generation Strategy set to None.
I retrive a question from my database and i change one string property and (after i save) my changes appear in my database.

How can I do to change the properties of an answer(for a specific question) to be visible into my database?

And i need to easy change code to another ORM (only change context and repository class).

Comment: You just approach code first with fluent configuration in EF

Comment: Are you asking how to update an Answer? That seems unrelated to the main focus of the question, which seems to be "how do I decouple my entities from the persistence mechanism?"

Comment: Yes this is the main focus of the question.Can you answer to that?